# Dealing with NA value while calculating age from the Date of Birth

Tags: r, missing-data

I am in a big problem. I have to calculate age and add a new column in the following table. I tried eeptools but can not deal with NA value

```
id DOB
1  5/22/1951
2  NA
3  8/18/1984
4  5/1/1994
5  NA
```

I tried the following code btw and it comes with an error. I want to deal with this NA value

```
Age= age_calc(as.Date(na.omit(Merged_data$DOB),"%m/%d/%Y"),units = "years")

Error in if (any(enddate < dob)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Please help, I have a deadline today :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is how we could do it:
I added an enddate.
First thing is to transform character into date format, we use mdy() function from lubridate.
then we can use `%–%` Operator that creates a time interval from the date of the birth to the enddate:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(-id, mdy),
         age = trunc((DOB %--% enddate) / years(1)))
```

```
    id DOB        enddate      age
  <int> <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1     1 1951-05-22 2022-01-01    70
2     2 NA         2022-01-01    NA
3     3 1984-08-18 2022-01-01    37
4     4 1994-05-01 2022-01-01    27
5     5 NA         2022-01-01    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean age as of today? If so, you could try the following base R approach. If by a certain date, just change `Sys.Date()` to a date-formatted date of interest:

```
df$age_years <- as.numeric((Sys.Date() - as.Date(df$DOB, "%m/%d/%Y")) / 365.25)
```

Output:

```
  id       DOB age_years
1  1 5/22/1951  71.43053
2  2      <NA>        NA
3  3 8/18/1984  38.18754
4  4  5/1/1994  28.48734
5  5      <NA>        NA
```

Comment: Hi, as.numaric needs any new package? Thanks I will try this

Comment: @mrinmoyee No, as.numeric() is a built-in function - you will not need any new package.

Comment: Hi @mrinmoyee - as Jas stated it is a base R function

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
df$age <- time_length(interval(as.Date(df$DOB, "%m/%d/%Y"), today()), unit = "years")
```

**Output**

```
  id       DOB      age
1  1 5/22/1951 71.43014
2  2      <NA>       NA
3  3 8/18/1984 38.18904
4  4  5/1/1994 28.48767
5  5      <NA>       NA
```